# Tabela de Frete - Listagem dos Bairros

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Tenho uma tabela chamada `bairro`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho uma tabela chamada `tabelafrete`: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho o seguinte SQL

```
public function getBairroList()
{       
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bairro as b Left join tabelafrete as t on b.idBairro = t.idDestino where t.idSaida = 1";
    return $this->db->query($sql)->result();    
}
```

Em que t.idSaida = 1 (1 = bairro de saída)

Funciona da seguinte forma:
Uma corrida do bairro Centro - Até o bairro Abranches, custa pela tabela, 2 pontos. Logo, saida = 1, chegada = 2... Mas enquanto eu listo todos os bairros, aparece apenas o que já está preenchido na tabela de frete.

Preciso: LISTAR todos os bairros, mesmo que não tiver preenchido os campos... para que de tal forma, não precise cadastrar um por um.

Preciso que seja desta forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você espera que apareça o quê no caso dos pares (saída, destino) que não estão cadastrados? Você quer ter uma fórmula grosseira pros casos gerais e adicionar exceções para trânsito, ladeira, …?

Comment: Minha intenção é listar todos os bairros... desde o ponto de partida.
- Partida: 1
- Bairro A, Bairro B, Bairro C... e neles vou definir cada valor.

Comment: Por que tirar o ` where t.idSaida = 1` não resolve o seu problema?

Comment: Tem tese, resolveria sim... porém, ele lista de todas as saídas e não apenas da saída 1. Como pode olhar no print, eu tenho duas saidas, 1 e 2, se eu tirar o where t.idSaida ele busca tanto saida 1, quanto saida 2, e teria que ser apenas a saida 1, no caso... se eu acrescento, ele lista apenas um registro, enquanto eu não cadastrar todos, não exibe na lista.

Comment: A saída são todos os bairros cadastrados na tabela bairros, tanto saída, quanto destinos, são os mesmos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seu SQL seja algo assim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bairro as b 
Left join tabelafrete as t on b.idBairro = t.idDestino and t.idSaida = '".$id."
```